# Send List<Integer> with POST method in Android

Tags: android, json, post, arraylist

I have to send a list of integers to a web service with my post method. The service reorders this list and returns it to me. So far, the service works fine. I have tested it in SoapUI and it successfully reorders my list and returns. However, I can't use it from Android. In more detail, I have the list;

```
List<Integer> productIds;
```

I have written the following method to call the service;

```
public void getSortedProductIds(boolean sync, AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler, List<Integer> productIds, Activity context) throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    initClient(sync);

    JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
    jsonParams.put("productIds", productIds);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
    System.out.println(entity);
    httpClient.post(context, WS_BASE_URL + "picker/sortbycategory", entity, "application/json",
            handler);
    return;

}
```

And on the Android side, I do the following to run this code;

```
getSortedProductIds(true, new AsyncResponseHandler() {                          
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int status, Header[] header, byte[] response) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = ResponseUtils.byteArrayToJsonObj(response);
        JSONArray jsonArr;
        try {
            jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(jsonArr.getInt(i));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    @Override
    public void onFailureAction(int status, Header[] header, byte[] responseBody, Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("fail");
        }
}, productIds, this);
```

However it is always ends in `onFailure` method. I couldn't get help from any solution on SA. What may be wrong here? How can we send a list of integers with post method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is solved. The problem is that I want to send an array of integers, however I am sending a JSON object that the serve side will not recognize;

```
jsonParams.put("productIds", productIds);
```

This JSON object contains the right values and it's valid, but the service wants directly an array (a JSON array). It cannot know that there is an array with "productIds" key inside this object. So, I had to send a JSONArray. First I formed my JSON array;

```
JSONArray x = new JSONArray();
for(Integer productId : productIds){
    x.put(productId);
}
```

Then I created the StringEntity and passed it via post method.

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(x.toString());
httpClient.post(context, WS_BASE_URL + "picker/sortbycategory", entity, "application/json",
    handler);
```

In case anyone encounters such a problem, just send the exact object/array in JSON format.